Assign Profile Card to CTA or link
Profile Card can be assigned to an item in Sitecore. Is there any way Profile card can be assigned to CTA or any link on a page ?

You can create an API to trigger the Profile card. This API can then be called on CTA/Link click through Javascript/jQuery.
API code to trigger Profile card would be as follows:
using Sitecore.Analytics;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Data;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public JsonResult TriggerProfileCard()
{
   if (!Tracker.IsActive || Tracker.Current == null)
   {
      Tracker.StartTracking();
   }

   CurrentInteraction interaction = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction;
   // Read the Profile Card Value of the Profile Card Item
   var profileCard = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{{ProfileCard_ItemID}}");
   Field field = profileCard.Fields["Profile Card Value"];
   var trackingField = new TrackingField(field);

   foreach (ContentProfile contentProfile in trackingField.Profiles)
   {
      if (contentProfile.IsSavedInField)
      { 
         string key = contentProfile.Key;
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
         {
            // update the profile with the score on the profile card
            Profile custProfile = interaction.Profiles[key];
            custProfile.Score((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, double>>)contentProfile);
         }
      }
   }
   return Json(new { isSuccess = true });
}

Above code, will trigger the Profile card and update the user profile.
Hope this helps!!!
